# Symfony2 - Dynamic DB entry editing

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, doctrine

I want to edit entries dynamically, as in: say I am the admin and I see an error in this post I can click `edit` and then Edit the text. Is this possible using php/symfony2/doctrine? or should I just  go with Ajax/jQuery?

Comment: Have you tried anything? judging by the vagueness of your question I'd say you didn't. Also: _"cut my losses and go with jQuery?"_ no reason to make things _worse_

Comment: One technique is server-side, the other is client-side. Both work well, I don't get what you mean by "cutting your losses". The best way is probably some combination of the two.

Comment: as I look at it now, idk what I meant either. I think It is finally sleep time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by dinamycally you mean "in the page where I am without reloading the full page" => then it has to see first with Ajax and so maybe JQuery (or any other JS Framework you enjoy). Behind this may stand symfony2 with Doctrine2 or whatever you want for your logic.

I can add that Symfony2 + the Doctrine2 Bundle provides default commands to generate CRUD on your entities (can be seen [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html))